# Hilbert Transform using CUDA

Tags: python, signal-processing, numba

In order to do a Hilbert transform on a 1D array, one must:

- FFT the array
- Double half the array, zero the other half
- Inverse-FFT the result

I'm using PyCuLib for the FFTing. My code so far

```
def htransforms(data):
    N = data.shape[0]
    transforms       = nb.cuda.device_array_like(data)          # Allocates memory on GPU with size/dimensions of signal
    transforms.dtype = np.complex64                             # Change GPU array type to complex for FFT 

    pyculib.fft.fft(signal.astype(np.complex64), transforms)    # Do FFT on GPU

    transforms[1:N/2]      *= 2.0      # THIS STEP DOESN'T WORK
    transforms[N/2 + 1: N]  = 0+0j     # NEITHER DOES THIS ONE

    pyculib.fft.ifft_inplace(transforms)                        # Do IFFT on GPU: in place (same memory)    
    envelope_function      = transforms.copy_to_host()          # Copy results to host (computer) memory
    return abs(envelope_function)
```

I have a feeling it may have something to do with Numba's CUDA interface itself... does it allow individual elements of an array (or array slices) to be modified like this? I assumed it might, as the variable `transforms` is a `numba.cuda.cudadrv.devicearray.DeviceNDArray`, so I thought maybe it had some of the same operations as numpy's `ndarray`.

In short, using Numba's `device_arrays`, what's the easiest way to do a simple operation on a slice? The error I get is

> unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'DeviceNDArray' and 'float'

Comment: What type is `data`? Your manipulation of the array dtype looks extremely suspicious

Comment: My input data is a standard ndarray of numpy.float64. I changed the transforms dtype to complex64 like that because device_array_like didn't support a dtype argument, and I'd assumed that both the input and output arrays would need to be the same type.

Comment: Changing the dtype doesn't change the data. It doesn't do anything, in fact. And makes no sense. A double precision complex number has a dtype of complex128, and a single precision complex number has a dtype of complex64. If you need to cast between types, use astype.

Comment: That's cool, I changed a few lines of code to take that into account, but the main issue I get is unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'DeviceNDArray' and 'float' - so I'm wondering if there's a way to modify this array in GPU memory in place.

Comment: Since it's a `DeviceNDArray`, you'll probably have to write a CUDA kernel to do the double-and-zero bits, if you want to do everything on the GPU. The examples over at http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.20.0/cuda/kernels.html#absolute-positions seem fairly straightforward.

Comment: Or, hey, you could probably call `cuBLAS.scal(2)` and `cuBLAS.scal(0)` on slices of the array. http://pyculib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cublas.html

Comment: AKX - Thanks! That worked perfectly. After not being able to directly modify slices of the array as above, I'd just assumed that maybe array slicing in general didn't work with device arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I would do using [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/)

Your function using pytorch (and I removed the abs to return the complex values)

```py
def htransforms(data):
    N = data.shape[-1]
    # Allocates memory on GPU with size/dimensions of signal
    transforms       = torch.tensor(data).cuda()
    
    torch.fft.fft(transforms, axis=-1)
    transforms[:, 1:N//2]      *= 2.0      # THIS STEP DOESN'T WORK
    transforms[:, N//2 + 1: N]  = 0+0j     # NEITHER DOES THIS ONE

    # Do IFFT on GPU: in place (same memory)
    return torch.abs(torch.fft.ifft(transforms)).cpu()
```

But your transform is actually different of what I find on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Discrete_Hilbert_transform)

The wikipedia version

```
def htransforms_wikipedia(data):
    N = data.shape[-1]
    # Allocates memory on GPU with size/dimensions of signal
    transforms       = torch.tensor(data).cuda()
    
    transforms = torch.fft.fft(transforms, axis=-1)
    transforms[:, 1:N//2]      *= -1j      # positive frequency
    transforms[:, (N+2)//2 + 1: N] *= +1j # negative frequency
    transforms[:,0] = 0; # DC signal
    if N % 2 == 0:
        transforms[:, N//2] = 0; # the (-1)**n term
    
    # Do IFFT on GPU: in place (same memory)
    return torch.fft.ifft(transforms).cpu()
```

```py
data = torch.zeros((1, 2**10))
data[:, 2**9] = 1;
tdata = htransforms(data).data;
plt.plot(tdata.real.T, '-')
plt.plot(tdata.imag.T, '-')
plt.xlim([500, 525])
plt.legend(['real', 'imaginary'])
plt.title('inpulse response of your version')
```

[image: result with your definition]

```py
data = torch.zeros((1, 2**10))
data[:, 2**9] = 1;
tdata = htransforms_wikipedia(data).data;
plt.plot(tdata.real.T, '-');
plt.plot(tdata.imag.T, '-');
plt.xlim([500, 525])
plt.legend(['real', 'imaginary'])
plt.title('inpulse response of Wikipedia version')
```

[image: result for wikipedia definition]

The impulse response for your version is `1 + 1j * h[k]` where `h[k]` is the impulse response of the wikipedia version. If you are working with real data the wikipedia version is nice because you can work with the [rfft](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/fft.html#torch.fft.rfft) and [irfft](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/fft.html#torch.fft.irfft) producing a one linear version

```py
def real_htransforms_wikipedia(data):
    N = data.shape[-1]
    # Allocates memory on GPU with size/dimensions of signal
    transforms       = torch.tensor(data).cuda()
    transforms = -1j * torch.fft.rfft(transforms, axis=-1)
    transforms[0] = 0;
    return torch.fft.irfft(transforms, axis=-1)
```